# Keeping memory in Tasks discrete

Tags: asp.net, thread-safety

I've heard a LOT in the past about how programming with Threads and Tasks is very dangerous to the naive.  Well, I'm naive, but I've got to learn sometime.  I am making a program (really, it's a Generic Handler for ASP.Net) that needs to call to a 3rd party and wait for a response.  While waiting, I'd like to have the handler continue doing some other things, so I am trying to figure out how to do the 3rd party web request asynchronously.  Based on some answers to some other questions I've received, here is what I've come up with, but I want to make sure I won't get into big problems when my handler is called multiple time concurrently.

To test this I've built a console project.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RunRequestAsynch test = new RunRequestAsynch();
        test.TestingThreadSafety = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        Console.WriteLine("Started:" + test.TestingThreadSafety);

        Task tTest = new Task(test.RunWebRequest);
        tTest.Start();

        while (test.Done== false)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Still waiting...");
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Done. " + test.sResponse);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

I instantiate a separate object (RunRequestAsynch) set some values on it, and then start it.  While that is processing I'm just outputting a string to the console window.

```
public class RunRequestAsynch
{
    public bool Done = false;
    public string sResponse = "";
    public string sXMLToSend = "";

    public string TestingThreadSafety = "";

    public RunRequestAsynch() { }


    public void RunWebRequest()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        // HttpWebRequest stuff goes here
        sResponse = TestingThreadSafety;
        Done = true;
        Thread.Sleep(500);

    }
}
```

So...if I run 1000 of these simultaneously, I can count on the fact that each instance has its own memory and properties, right?  And that the line "Done = true;" won't fire and then every one of the instances of the Generic Handler die, right?

I wrote a .bat file to run several instances, and the guid I set on each specific object seems to stay the same for each instance, which is what I want...but I want to make sure I'm not doing something really stupid that will bite me in the butt under full load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any glaring problems, however you should [consider using the Factory.StartNew instead of Start](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/06/13/10024153.aspx). Each task will only be executed once, so there isn't any problem with multiple tasks running simultaneously.

If you want to simplify your code a little and take advantage of the Factory.StartNew, in your handler you could do something like this (from what I remember of your last question):

```
Task<byte[]> task = Task.Factory.StartNew<byte[]>(() =>    // Begin task
{
    //Replace with your web request, I guessed that it's downloading data
    //change this to whatever makes sense
    using (var wc = new System.Net.WebClient())
        return wc.DownloadData("Some Address");
});

//call method to parse xml, will run in parallel

byte[] result = task.Result;  // Wait for task to finish and fetch result.
```

Comment: I got my original code from a link you provided before, that showed both methods (the one I used and also the Factory.StartNew method).  I tried them both.  I THOUGHT that I kept the Factory.StartNew method, but evidently I went 1 step too far on Undo.  I'll definitely use the StartNew version.  Thanks for the help, Brandon.

Comment: Yes it did.  If you are asking because you want me to accept the answer, yes, I will do so.  Sometimes I like to leave the question open for a couple of hours to see if any other answers are forthcoming.